# Как убрать имя шаблона WordPress из url

Tags: wordpress

**Всем доброго времени суток.**

Есть шаблон на Wordpress "Amy Movie". Но проблема в том, что на страницах в URL строке выводит название шаблона.

В URL так *hosting.host/**amy_movie**/page*

Как его убрать?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Permalinks]
Попробуй сменить настройки во вкладке пермалинков. Если это купленная тема, то это там меняется